# Почему не получается создать перегруженный метод в C#?

Tags: c#

Я только учусь. Уже больше часа безуспешно потратил на поиск решения. Как понял проблема из-за какого-то верхнего уровня. Может кто знает как решить эту проблему? Пример в фотографии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код должен быть в вопросе текстом. Картинки допустимы в качестве дополнения вопроса

Comment: Полагаю потому, что это всё не внутри класса....то есть это не методы, а просто функции

Comment: Вы пишете код используя так называемые [Операторы верхнего уровня ( top level statements)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements), которые имеют свои возможности, правила, ограничения. Вообще, операторы верхнего уровня это метод `Main` под капотом, внутрь которого помещается ваш код, то есть написав просто `Console.WriteLine()`, компилятор за вас создаст `public class Program { public void Main() { Console.WriteLine() } }`, ну а переопределять метод внутри метода невозможно, вот и ваша ошибка. Поэтому, тут только создавать класс.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да как так-то? Может, там какой-то класс по-умолчанию?

Comment: @rotabor нет [​](https://google.com)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вот EvgeniyZ говорит, что есть

Comment: @rotabor он говорит, что не явно это превращается в класс

Comment: `ну а переопределять метод внутри метода невозможно, вот и ваша ошибка.` - @EvgeniyZ вы имели ввиду "перегружать", а не "переопределять", верно?

Comment: Если кратко, автор объявляет не методы, а локальные функции, а перегрузка для локальных функций невозможна.

Comment: @rotabor  https://dotnetfiddle.net/eojXfO   .... эта фича появилась не так давно просто....... в .NET 5 )))

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Да не так немного выразился, спасибо что поправили.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечу, чтобы был понятный и полный ответ.

Ваш код эквивалентен следующему (см. комментарий EvgeniyZ):

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        void Test (int a) {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        void Test (string a) {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Поэтому получилось, что Test - зто не методы, которые можно перегружать, а [локальные функции](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) метода Main.

Чтобы получить то, что вы хотите, вам нужно пересоздать проект без использования операторов верхнего уровня (или создать отдельный класс) и написать следующее:

```
public class Program {
    static void Test (int a) { // public as required
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    static void Test (string a) { // public as required
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    public static void Main() {
        // main code here
    }
}
```

Это и будет перегрузка метода Test в классе Program.

Comment: Вы сейчас придираетесь к мелочам, ради чего? Что понятней для новичка будет "Метод внутри метода", или "Локальная функция внутри метода"? И вообще, у нас помню с вами договоренность была, вы не лезете ко мне, я не лезу к вам, пожалуйста, соблюдайте ее, а то я ведь тоже могу придраться к множеству ваших ответов. Всего наилучшего!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не придираюсь, вам AndreiKhotko всё написал. Вы специалист, видно по всему, и ответы всегда даёте качественные, а тут просто немного смазали. Я считаю, что новичку лучше сразу сказать про локальные функции, а не ждать, пока повзрослеет :-). И вам не хворать!

Answer (score 1):

В чём разница между **методом** и **функцией**? В том, что **метод** строго привязан к классу. Вы создали **функции** внутри исполняемого файла Program.cs. Вы можете это сделать, но это не является ошибкой, но только в рамках **класса**

Comment: Это бред, мягко говоря. Хотя бы потому, что в c# нельзя "создали функции внутри исполняемого файла Program.cs".

Comment: @rotabor  всё можно, не надо дезинформировать никого

Comment: @АлексейШиманский здесь всё не так. Функции и подпрограммы (или как они там называются) можно создавать внутри методов, а не внутри "исполняемого файла" (что это за чать кода такая?).

Comment: @rotabor если вам это не нравится - ещё не значит, что это нельзя делать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не сказал, что мне "это" не нравится, а сказал, что Вы, конкретно, вместе с Faraday и EvgeniyZ выразились некорректно.

Comment: @rotabor Меня сюда не приплетайте, я дал ссылку на документацию и сказал как там под капотом все работает. Не верите, вот вам [пример](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKnAnACgESHwQQAiCAcIIEwggrCCBCIAITYCUA3EA==) того, о чем я писал. Если чего-то лично в моих словах нашли не то, напишите лично мне, а не где-то за моей спиной.

Comment: @rotabor, я не говорил, что их там нельзя создавать